# iOS - how to get kind of class of delegate

Tags: ios, delegates

How can I get the kind of class of my delegate?
I would like to call something like `self.delegate.class`, but it doesn't exist.

My goal is to call 2 different methods depending on which class was the one who initiated the class who has the protocols.

Comment: [self.delegate class] . class is a selector not a property.

Comment: @Kampai Don't I set a certain class to be the delegate of another class?

Comment: @OnikIV is doesn't work for me. It says "not know instance method for selector class".

Comment: I think you should explain what is your goal for wanting to use that and maybe here people can point you to the best solution or suggest a path.

Comment: If you are a object, It has a delegate property: (@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocolDelegate> delegate;) and inside its implementation you call NSLog(@"View my delegate %@",[[self.delegate class] description]); and Its delegate is pointing to a valid object, you will see the delegate's class.

Comment: If It doesn't exist, you might call this before you are point to a no nil object.

Comment: The nature of a delegate is that you do not need to know what class it is. By detecting the class of a delegate and acting differently on it depending on the class you are breaking the fundamental concept of using delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use **respondsToSelector** to check if that delegate is able to respond to that selector, instead of trying to figure it out the class.

Example:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method1:)]) {
     [self.delegate method1:self];
} else if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method2:)]) {
     [self.delegate method2:self];
}
```

And you only implement each method in the classes you want, but both of them are on the delegate protocol. Does this approach meet your needs?

Like others have commented and answered, whoever calls the delegate does not need to know what class or type he is, only needs to check if that delegate conforms to protocol and if responds to the method you want to call on him.

More info about respondsToSelector @ [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using delegate protocols is to decouple the object doing the work from the type of class that is acting on the work done.

In fact, the very nature of a delegate is that you don't **care** what class it is. All you care is that it **conforms to the protocol** and therefore will have a set of known functions that can be run on it.

A delegate could be a `UIView`, `UIViewController`, `UILabel` or any custom class that you want it to be.

By detecting the class and then acting on it differently depending on the class you are breaking the fundamental principle that delegates and protocols are trying to get around in the first place which is tightly coupled objects.

Also, the class with the delegate should not know what is happening to the data and it shouldn't care either. A `UITableView` for instance doesn't know what happens when its delegate responds to a selected cell. That delegate could update something in CoreData or transition to a new ViewController. The table view doesn't (and shouldn't) know this.

Your object should say something like... `HELLO DELEGATE! Something just happened and this is the result, just wanted to let you know`. The delegate then takes that result and acts on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old but in case anyone is looking for a way to do this, here is the way.

Aside from the fact that you shouldn´t be coupling to the delegate type (that is the whole purpose of the pattern) that was accurately stated in the other answers, I faced the same requirement and I think the question was not answered properly.
I was replacing a view controller with an updated version and, for debug reasons,  I needed both view controllers to be functional at the same time. Because of a feature that I am developing, I need to change an object method implementation that would break the old one and I managed to solve it like this:

```
[(NSObject*)_delegate isKindOfClass:[YourType class]];
```

So basically casting the `delegate` to a NSObject gives you access to the class selector and you can then make a decision based on the type of the delegate. This way I was able to preserve the old implementation to work with the old view controller and also add the new implementation in an `else` clause that would be executed in the case that the `delegate` is of type `NewViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

For your question: call  `[delegate class]`

Now you have the class delegate.

**Note:** If your delegate is nil, `[delegate class]` doesn't respond.

**Note2:** Put a debug statement checking to see the delegate class. Also you can put a debug statement checking to see is delegate nil?